# Why don't we get shown a suggested edit after we have approved it?

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits

After approving a suggested edit, we still get displayed the original version of the post until a second user approves the same edit.

Wouldn't it make sense to show the suggested edit after approving it? Especially re-formatting edits make reading questions much easier and sometimes it can take quite a while until a second user approves the edit.

Comment: But what if it gets rejected finally?

Comment: No, in my opinion it won't make much sense and will only be confusing. I like to see the real data.

Comment: @DanielFischer: if it gets rejected finally, simply switch back to the original version.

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd: maybe display a banner »This edit is not final, it is only displayed because you have approved it« – quite similar to the current »This edit still needs another approve vote before it gets final« message

Comment: No, I saw this mechanism in other sites where I have less than 2K rep and was suggesting edits and honestly find this "only you can see the edit until it's approved" confusing as well. It's just my personal opinion though, others might agree with you. :)

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd: yeah, but that's your personal edit – I'd like to see your edit after I have approved it (why else would I approve it, if I don't expect it to show up?)

Comment: Interesting point of view, but in my case I approve it because I think it's correct. I still prefer to see the "live" status of the post, not the status I want it to be in.